# 502 Bad Gateway после отправки приложения на хостинг

Tags: python, django

По книге Eric Matthes, Python Crash Course, написал приложение Learning Log на Django.
Чтобы развернуть приложение на хостинге Platform.sh установил CLI (Command Line Interface) в Git Bash с помощью команды `$ curl -fsS https://platform.sh/cli/installer | php`.
Создал файл `requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
Django==4.2.2
django-bootstrap4==23.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
packaging==23.1
platformshconfig==2.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.7
soupsieve==2.4.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.6.3
tzdata==2023.3
```

и `requirements_remote.txt`:

```
gunicorn
psycopg2
```

Затем файлы конфигурации `.platform.app.yaml`:

```
type: "python:3.10"

relationships:
    database: "db:postgresql"

# The configuration of the app when it's exposed to the web.
web:
    upstream:
        socket_family: unix
    commands:
        start: "gunicorn -w 4 -b unix:$SOCKET ll_project.wsgi:application"
    locations:
        "/":
            passthru: true
        "/static":
            root: "static"
            expires: 1h
            allow: true

# The size of the persistent disk of the application (in MB).
disk: 512

# Set a local read/write mount for logs.
mounts:
    "logs":
        source: local
        source_path: logs

# The hooks executed at various points in the lifecycle of the application.
hooks:
    build: |
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install -r requirements_remote.txt
        
        mkdir logs
        python manage.py collectstatic
        rm -rf logs
    deploy: |
        python manage.py migrate
```

`routes.yaml`:

```
"https://{default}/":
    type: upstream
    upstream: "ll_project:http"

"https://www.{default}/":
    type: redirect
    to: "https://{default}/"
```

`services.yaml`:

```
db:
    type: postgresql:12
    disk: 1024
```

Добавил в `settings.py`:

```
# Platform.sh settings.
from platformshconfig import Config

config = Config()
if config.is_valid_platform():
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append('.platformsh.site')
    DEBUG = False

    if config.appDir:
        STATIC_ROOT = Path(config.appDir) / 'static'
    if config.projectEntropy:
        SECRET_KEY = config.projectEntropy

    if not config.in_build():
        db_settings = config.credentials('database')
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
                'NAME': db_settings['path'],
                'USER': db_settings['username'],
                'PASSWORD': db_settings['password'],
                'HOST': db_settings['host'],
                'PORT': db_settings['port'],
    },
}
```

В создаю файл `gitignore`, в Git Bash добавляю файлы, делаю commit, отправляю проект командой `platform push`.
В личном кабинете хостера проект появляется но при переходе по ссылке я в браузере получаю 502 Bad Gateway.
Я новичок в программировании, подскажите что не так?
Спасибо за внимание!